# How do I tell Legend of Zelda NES versions apart?

Tags: nes, the-legend-of-zelda

I've recently become interested in collecting old NES games. I'm trying to find an original NES Legend of Zelda game CIB. However, I'm having trouble distinguishing different versions of the game. All of the Legend of Zelda games have a box, owner's manual, cartridge, sleeve, styrofoam, and a map with secrets. However, when I search on eBay for Legend of Zelda games (CIB), I get several variations. Namely, different games vary on extras in the box (i.e. a Nintendo Power poster, an invitation to subscribe to Nintendo, an invitation to join the Nintendo fun club, etc.) According to Wikipedia, the original NES version had the invitation to join the Nintendo fun club, but I really have no idea if that's correct. When I see different Legend of Zelda game boxes, some say Rev 1, others say Rev A. I would like to get as early a release as I can find.

My question is: How can I tell which versions of Legend of Zelda NES are early and which ones aren't? Moreover, is it possible to identify a "first edition" Legend of Zelda game, or anything similar?

I've tried extensive Googling but to no avail. I have found a few different online databases but nothing with the information I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might see if you can find any old commercials for when the game was just released. As they will do production of the commercial from before the game was released, if they have any box art it will likely be the first edition box art or still pre-production.

Answer (score 4):

When a game has "Rev (x)" on the label, it usually means it has already been revised. This means that it is *not* the original release, and is more than likely a newer release with bug fixes etc. The original release *shouldn't* have any revisions on the label.

As for which is newer - A or 1: it's more than likely that this is the same version of the game, just released in different countries. I don't remember off the top of my head if there was still a PAL/NTSC variation back then - but that may have something to do with it.